# Compare two columns Excel

Tags: excel

I want to compare two columns to validate that they are the same but the problem I have is that one of the columns has its content in quotes an examples:

Column A = 123456
Column B = '123456'

How can I buy the data but ignoring the single quotes?

Someone can help me.

Thank you.***emphasized text***

Answer (score 0):

Is the data always a number?

Try SUBSTITUTE to remove the ':
*=A1=SUBSTITUTE(A2, "'")*.

This won't work probably because it's a text with number comparison. With VALUE you convert the text to numbers. So that makes it:

*=A1=VALUE(SUBSTITUTE(B1,"'",""))*

Comment: We also have a string that can contain '' how do you remove the first and last character?

Comment: When it's always the last and first character, =MID(B1,2,LENGTH(B1)-2). Please tag it as the answer if it worked, please.

Answer (score 0):

You can first get rid of the single quote from list B by using find and replace. Select list B. Press Control H. Find ' and replace all with nothing.
Now u can select both columns under comparison apply conditional formatting duplicate value/unique value as per ur requirement. For other challenges during comparison this can be referred to
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5fsmy3uwoc8